# Authenticating Apache HTTPServer 2.4.x with mod_auth_gssapi using Microsoft Active directory

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, sasl, gssapi

I'm looking for below configurations for GSSAPI authentication with Apache 2.4 for Active directory:

**1.** How to configure Apache HTTPServer 2.4.x with [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi) using Microsoft Active directory? Is there any **documentation** OR **POC example** stating the required configuration to do in Apache HTTPServer 2.4.x for GSSAPI, So as to authenticate using GSSAPI mechanism with Microsoft Active directory?

**2.** Does [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi)  provides **Integrity** & **Confidentiality** security services? If yes then what configuration is required to do in Apache HTTPServer?
 *[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1331/overview-6/index.html) for Integrity & Confidentiality in GSSAPI.*

As per my analysis, the Active directory supports GSSAPI SASL mechanism. But, Apache HTTPserver does not support GSSAPI as an out of box configuration. However, using [**mod_auth_gssapi**](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi) it's possible for Apache HTTPServer to lookup for users & their credentials in Active directory and thereby authenticate using GSSAPI mechanism.

Currently, I'm having Basic authentication provider configured as below in Apache HTTPServer, which needs to be replaced with mod_auth_gssapi to implement gssapi authentication mechanism:

```
# Basic Authentication provider

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap MyEnterpriseLdap>
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://machine1.abcd.com:389/CN=Users,DC=abcd,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=rohit,CN=Users,DC=abcd,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "abc123"
  LDAPReferrals Off
</AuthnProviderAlias>

# Authenticated resources

<LocationMatch ^/+WebApp/+(;.*)?>
  AuthName "WebApp"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider MyEnterpriseLdap 
  Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make GSSAPI work using the following tutorial:
[http://www.jfcarter.net/~jimc/documents/bugfix/41-auth-kerb.html](http://www.jfcarter.net/%7Ejimc/documents/bugfix/41-auth-kerb.html)

What I did (I'm on Debian)

## Join the domain

Install packages:

```sh
apt-get install --no-install-recommends winbind smbclient krb5-config krb5-user libldap-common
```

In `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

    ### My changes ###
    default_realm = MY-DOMAIN.FR
    default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    # AD in 2008+? Using AES
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    ### end ###

[realms]
    MY-DOMAIN.FR = {
        kdc = ad1.my-domain.fr
        kdc = ad2.my-domain.fr
        master_kdc = ad1.my-domain.fr
        admin_server = ad1.my-domain.fr
        default_domain = my-domain.fr
        # Hack to remove the '@my-domain.fr' part of the user login, to only keep the prefix (facultative. Used to simplify my PHP auth mechanism)
        # Source: http://comp.protocols.kerberos.narkive.com/57JV8mmf/libapache2-mod-auth-kerb-and-cross-realm
        #       (Greg Hudson)
        auth_to_local = RULE:[1:$1@$0](.*@my-domain.fr)s/@my-domain.fr$//
        auth_to_local = DEFAULT
    }

[domain_realm]
    .my-domain.fr = MY-DOMAIN.FR
    my-domain.fr = MY-DOMAIN.FR
```

In `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
    workgroup           = MY-DOMAIN
    realm               = MY-DOMAIN.FR
    security            = ADS
    encrypt passwords   = yes
    password server     = ad1.my-domain.fr
    kerberos method     = system keytab

(the rest of the file is unmodified)
```

Disable referrals for LDAP calls:

```sh
/bin/echo 'REFERRALS off' >> /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
```

**Join the domain:**

```sh
kinit administrateur
  # (use an admin AD account)
```

```sh
net ads join -U administrateur createcomputer=OU=Member\ servers,DC=my-domain,DC=fr
  # (specify where you want to store the object in your AD.
  # I translated the name in English, so 'Member Servers' is just an example
```

## Keytab for http

Create a keytab in `/etc/krb5.keytab`:

```sh
net ads keytab add HTTP -U administrateur
```

Protect it: (in my case, `www-data` is the Unix user used for serving web pages)

```
chmod 640 /etc/krb5.keytab
chown root:www-data /etc/krb5.keytab
```

I added a script in the crontab to renew this keytab once a day. Not sure it is still needed, but on previous versions of Debian I had some bugs when the file was outdated. So I made a script in Expect calling `net ads keytab add HTTP -U my-linux.ad-account` for me. And it is still there :)

## Configure Apache

Get GSSAPI for Apache:

```sh
apt-get install --no-install-recommends libapache2-mod-auth-gssapi
```

Activating session cookies (to avoid reauthenticate user on each page) - facultative

```sh
a2enmod session
a2enmod session_cookie
```

In your Apache site config (eg. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    DocumentRoot /your/web/root

    <Directory /your/web/root>
        AuthType                GSSAPI
        AuthName                "My Domain"
        GssapiCredStore         keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
        GssapiAcceptorName      HTTP
        GssapiBasicAuth         On
        GssapiNegotiateOnce     On
        GssapiSSLonly           On
        GssapiLocalName         On
        # Use a cookie to keep the session, avoid reauthenticate user on each page
        # (facultative)
        GssapiUseSessions       On
        GssapiDelegCcacheDir    /run/apache2/clientcaches
        <IfModule mod_session.c>
            Session on
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_session_cookie.c>
            SessionCookieName gssapi_session path=/;httponly;secure;
        </IfModule>

        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache and pray

```sh
service apache2 restart
```

I hope I didn't forget anything.

**Footing notes:** the web clients won't delegate their credentials (and the SSO will not work) if:

- your webserver is not in TLS (`SSLEngine on`)
- your webserver is not in the clients trusted sites ("Intranet Sites" of your Internet settings, for example)

Comment: SSO should be completely independent from credential delegation. Only in RDP they're tied together, elsewhere in Kerberos they aren't. (Requiring unconstrained delegation to any random webserver is somewhat of a security risk, too...)

Comment: Regarding keytab updates, it might be because you're using the "machine" keys for the webserver. (Again not a very good idea.) Like Windows, Samba will change the machine account's password every month or so, which makes the old keytab invalid. You can however configure smb.conf to automatically provide a keytab (iirc, the "kerberos method" option). Still, a better approach would be to create a separate *user* account in AD that'll represent the web server; assign the HTTP/foo SPN to it; and make a keytab for that account – independent from the machine. Wouldn't even require the domain join.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for your advices. I'll try, and will update my answer if I manage to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: I managed to make it work with a user account, activating delegation on it (and do not use samba anymore). But as the Linux web server is not in the domain anymore, I have to allow delegation for "all services (Kerberos only)". (I can't restrict the delegation to a specific HTTP service on a specific host). So I'm not sure it is more secure. What would be the "state of the art" way of doing this?

Comment: Ah, so you *were* specifically using constrained delegation when you had the "full domain join" method. I didn't realize that. Regardless, I'd say the answer is to not use delegation _at all_... there's nothing in this entire thread that would indicate delegation being necessary.